# Looping and returning all values in a dictionary

Tags: python

Whenever I execute the code below it only returns one total_hours instead of all hours in the value arrays

```
worker_hours = {'John': [8,8,4,3,8],
                'Leo': [5,6,7,8,9],
                'Sammy': [4,5,6,8,8],
                'Ken': [8,8,8,8,8]}

def calc_check(worker_list):
    worker = ''
    total_hours = 0
    for worker in worker_list:
        total_hours = sum(worker_list[worker]) * 13
    return total_hours

print(calc_check(worker_hours))
```

How would i go about printing out the keys and the total hours in the list * payrate on new lines? so far I have:

```
def calc_check(worker_list):
  workers = ''
  total_hours = 0
  for worker in worker_list:
     total_hours = sum(worker_list[worker])
     pay = total_hours * 13
     return print("{}'s total check amount is {}".format(worker,pay))

print(calc_check(worker_hours))
```

Comment: need += instead of =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *replacing* the `total` value each time:

```
for worker in worker_list:
    total_hours = sum(worker_list[worker]) * 13
```

If you wanted to *add* the result of the expression to the running total, use addition, or better yet, augmented assignment:

```
for worker in worker_list:
    total_hours += sum(worker_list[worker]) * 13
```

Note that you don't have to predefine `worker`. You could loop over the *values* of `worker_list` (which is really a dictionary, not a list), and you could sum the sums with a nested expression:

```
def calc_check(workers):
    return sum(sum(hours) * 13 for hours in workers.values())
```

or sum all list numbers by chaining them, then multiplying that sum by 13:

```
from itertools import chain

def calc_check(workers):
    return sum(chain.from_iterable(workers.values())) * 13
```

Demo:

```
>>> worker_hours = {
...     'John': [8, 8, 4, 3, 8],
...     'Leo': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
...     'Sammy': [4, 5, 6, 8, 8],
...     'Ken': [8, 8, 8, 8, 8]}
>>> def calc_check(workers):
...     return sum(sum(hours) * 13 for hours in workers.values())
... 
>>> calc_check(worker_hours)
1781
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> def calc_check(workers):
...     return sum(chain.from_iterable(workers.values())) * 13
... 
>>> calc_check(worker_hours)
1781
```

Comment: @Rainmaker drop the `return` statement, *or* build one big string and return that. Your `return print(..)` exits the loop and function immediately (thus limiting you to the first worker) and returns `None` (the return value of the `print()` function).